# Create Circular Reveal for Pre-Lollipop Devices

Tags: android, animation, material-design, animator

First thing's first, this is not the same question as [Create circular reveal for pre-Lollipop devices (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544800/create-circular-reveal-for-pre-lollipop-devices-android)

I am using the library mentioned there to create Circular Reveal, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

**XML**

```
<io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/circBack"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff4081"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            ></FrameLayout>
</io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
                View myView = findViewById(R.id.circBack);


                // get the center for the clipping circle
                int cx = (myView.getLeft() + myView.getRight()) / 2;
                int cy = (myView.getTop() + myView.getBottom()) / 2;

                // get the final radius for the clipping circle
                int finalRadius = Math.max(myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight());


                SupportAnimator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
                animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                animator.setDuration(1000);
                myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                animator.start();
```

The circular reveal doesn't show up. I mean nothing happens when the code executes.

**Logcat** shows this

```
07-01 19:15:47.498  27556-27556/com.ledo.ledoapp I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.codetail.animation.RevealAnimator$RevealRadius>

07-01 19:15:47.498  27556-27556/com.ledo.ledoapp I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.codetail.animation.RevealAnimator$RevealRadius>

07-01 19:15:47.498  27556-27556/com.ledo.ledoapp I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.codetail.animation.RevealAnimator$RevealRadius>

07-01 19:15:47.501  27556-27556/com.ledo.ledoapp I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.codetail.animation.ViewAnimationUtils$SimpleAnimationListener>

07-01 19:15:47.501  27556-27556/com.ledo.ledoapp I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.codetail.animation.ViewAnimationUtils$SimpleAnimationListener>

07-01 19:15:47.502  27556-27556/com.ledo.ledoapp I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.codetail.animation.RevealAnimator$RevealFinishedGingerbread>

07-01 19:15:47.502  27556-27556/com.ledo.ledoapp I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.codetail.animation.RevealAnimator$RevealFinishedGingerbread>

07-01 19:15:47.502  27556-27556/com.ledo.ledoapp I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.codetail.animation.RevealAnimator$RevealFinishedIceCreamSandwich>

07-01 19:15:47.503  27556-27556/com.ledo.ledoapp I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.codetail.animation.RevealAnimator$RevealFinishedIceCreamSandwich>

07-01 19:15:47.503  27556-27556/com.ledo.ledoapp I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.codetail.animation.RevealAnimator$RevealFinishedJellyBeanMr2>

07-01 19:15:47.503  27556-27556/com.ledo.ledoapp I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.codetail.animation.RevealAnimator$RevealFinishedJellyBeanMr2>
```

However the circular reveal does work if the view is set to visible in the XML files, but the problem is if I set the view "**circBack**" to visible in the XML, it shows up from the moment the app is launched, which is usual.

Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it might be an issue with the Gradle dependency as it worked when I added the library in this way,

**Wrong Way**

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

**Right Way**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1'
}
```

Sorry for the late answer though. Hope it helps someone in need.

Answer (score 2):

Look like you're initializing this animation on "Gone" view ?

Try to get view's visibilty and make sure that you run it inside

```
if (mView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
{
..
..
  anim.start();
}
```

block of code.

Comment: I had the view set to "invisible" and not "gone".

Comment: yeah, i said it just as a reference.. ttis kind of error comes when you call animation on invisible or gone view.