# how to show circle animation on click in android

Tags: android, material-design

i am new to android and reading Material Design i am looking for how to design an animation like this animation

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code you've already done?

Comment: That's actually talked about in this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958834/circular-reveal-transition-for-new-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This animation is provided on Android API version 21. [From the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Reveal):

The ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal() method enables you to animate a clipping circle to reveal or hide a view.

```
// previously invisible view
View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);

// get the center for the clipping circle
int cx = myView.getWidth() / 2;
int cy = myView.getHeight() / 2;

// get the final radius for the clipping circle
float finalRadius = (float) Math.hypot(cx, cy);

// create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
Animator anim =
    ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

// make the view visible and start the animation
myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
anim.start();
```

Comment: If you care for API  < 21 support, you should check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28604515/1340659

Comment: thanks you saved my day!

Comment: how to give color to circle ?